# Can't get php password_verify() to work

Tags: php, postgresql, login-script, password-hash

I'm using php 7 and postgres and I'm failing to get this password hash thing down.

Here's my user Registration.  It's outputting passwords to the db similar to "$2y$10$1GWNRZokmwGR1/dxnMRiOuw4/dNh2IzH9O2QvIu5wjlLAX2OZRW5G" which seems to work:

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $required_fields = array('username', 'password', 'confirm_password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email_address', 'phone',
        'department', 'group_role');
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'Fields marked with asterisk are required';
            break 1;
        }
    }
}

if (empty($errors) === true) {
    if (user_exists($_POST['username']) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, the username \'' . $_POST['username'] . '\' is already taken';
    }
    if (preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST['username']) == true) {
        $errors[] = 'Your useranme must not contain any spaces';
    }
    if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 14) {
        $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 14 characters';
    }
    if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['confirm_password']) {
        $errors[] = 'You passwords do not match';
    }
    if (filter_var($_POST['email_address'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'A valid email address is required';
    }
    if (email_exists($_POST['email_address']) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, this email \'' . $_POST['email_address'] . '\' is already registered';
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
    include 'include/iHead.php';
    include 'include/widgets/login.php';
    include 'include/widgets/login_report.php';
    if (empty($errors) === false) {
        ?>
        <h3>Registration Successful! You will receive an email once your registration is approved. </h3>
        <?php
        include 'include/widgets/login_rpt.php';
    }
} else {
    if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
        $user_req = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
        $register_data = array(
            'username' => $_POST['username'],
            'password' => $hashedPassword,
            'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
            'email_address' => $_POST['email_address'],
            'phone' => $_POST['phone'],
            'department' => $_POST['department'],
            'region' => $_POST['region'],
            'group_role' => $_POST['group_role'],
            'active' => 0
        );
        register_user($register_data);
        header('Location: register.php?success');
        exit();
    } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
        include 'include/iHead.php';
        include 'include/widgets/login.php';
        include 'include/widgets/login_report.php';
        if (empty($errors) === false) {
            ?>
            <h3>Registration unsuccessful: </h3>
            <?php
            echo output_errors($errors);
            include 'include/widgets/login_rpt.php';
        }
    }
}
function email_exists($email) {
    $email = sanitize($email);
//    echo "SELECT COUNT (userid) FROM user_profiles WHERE email_address = '$email'";
    return (pg_fetch_result(pg_query("SELECT COUNT (userid) FROM user_profiles WHERE email_address = '$email'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
?>
```

And here is my login script:

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a username and password';
    } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Username not found.  Please register.';
    } else if (user_active($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Account not active';
    } else {

        if (strlen($password) > 32) {
            $errors[] = 'Password too long';
        }

        $hash = login($username, $password);
        if (password_verify($password, "$hash")) {
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $login;
            header('Location: main.php');
            exit;
        } else {
            $errors[] = " Username & Password are incorrect";
        }
    }
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
include 'include/iHead.php';
include 'include/widgets/login.php';
include 'include/widgets/login_report.php';
if (empty($errors) === false) {
    ?>
    <h3>login unsuccessful: </h3>
    <?php
    echo output_errors($errors);
    include 'include/widgets/login_rpt.php';
    include 'include/eFoot.php';
}
function login($username, $password) {
    $user_id = get_id($username);
    $username = sanitize($username);
//    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $row = pg_fetch_assoc(pg_query("SELECT password FROM user_profiles WHERE username = '$username'"));
    $hash = $row['password'];
    return $hash;
}
?>
```

I'm new to php, so any help would be outstanding!!!

Comment: You should just test against the password, not this `$hash = login($username, $password);` It should be `(password_verify($password, $hash)` where `$hash` is what you retrieve from the database, the stored hash.

Comment: Allow users to use the [passwords / phrases](https://xkcd.com/936/) they desire.

[Don't limit passwords.](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html).

Comment: [Could you please remove all stuff from your question that is not related to the actual problem?](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Make sure you actually get the hashed password from the db.

Comment: Side note: I would highly suggest using `require` or `require_once` over include. At least, in the manner I see you using it here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thank you for your answers, but none of you were correct.  I had to use pg_escape_string prior to the hash and verify functions.  Simple, simple, simple....